# What is the server and port to authenticate on jetbrains?

Tags: resharper

I have a subscription to Resharper and I want to use in my work, but we are behind a firewall that blocks my login attempts.

I need to give to infrastructure team the ip and port address that resharper uses to login, but I cannot find it on google.

Any one have it?

PS: Maybe this forum is not ideal to ask this. If it so, in what forum I can ask?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/support/

Comment: Thanks, I will ask on jetbrains forums too